# Binding in $(document).ready(); does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, binding

I need to call a function when a search is executed. The search is based on an input field, must not necessary be integrated in a form. I just need the value of the search field.

As I need some functionality of the framework - this is processing markdown files - I have to place the binding in the existing `$(document).ready();` part.

I struggle to get it work.

#### Document ready part with my binding

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // stage init stuff
    registerFetchConfig();
    registerBuildNavigation();
    extractHashData();

    appendDefaultFilenameToHash();

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
        window.location.reload(false);
    });


    loadContent($.md.mainHref); // this parts generates the HTML for the page

    // the part I integrated 
    console.log( ':: Before binding' );
    $( '#srch-term' ).change( function(  ) { 
        alert( "change" );
        console.log( '### This is a binding on submit' );
    } );
    /*
    $( '#subsearch' ).on( 'click', function(  ) {  
            alert( "### This is binding on clicking the button" );
    } );
    */
    console.log( ':: After binding' );
    // end of my part   
});
```

#### Searchfield in the same html page

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" id="searchform" onsubmit="return false">
   <div class="input-group">
     <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
     <div class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="subsearch">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
       </button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

The file itself is available online: [mdwiki-debug.html](http://jerik.github.io/mdwiki-debug.html#!index.md) and based on [MDwiki](http://dynalon.github.io/mdwiki/#!index.md)

In the firebug console I see the two entries

```
:: Before binding
:: After binding
```

But when I enter a string in the search field and hit enter or click the button, nothings shows up in the console.

I tried as well to bind submit, but this did not work either. Furthermore the form should not be submitted in the end, as I have to avoid a reload. Thats why I have `onsubmit="return false"` in the form tag.

**How do I get the bindings to work, when the search field is filled and the user hits enter or clicks the button?**

Comment: is the searchform in the page when you try to attempt to bind do it? if not, a delegated event handler might be appropriate. e.g. `$(document).on('click', '#subsearch', function(e) { ... });`

Comment: I am not sure, as I do not now to figure this out: when the searchform is available. Ok will try the delegate event handler.

Comment: [As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated.](https://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: @Teemu ``$(window).bind()`` is used by the framework and they are using not jQuery 3.0, so thats fine. I saw that in the documentaion as well.

Comment: @Dymos works fine with the delegate. If you write an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `searchform` is not the page when you attempt to bind do it, jQuery won't find the element so it doesn't have an element to bind the event handler to.

In this case a delegated event handler might be appropriate because the event handler will be bound to an element known to already exist. A commonly used way to do this is to bind event handlers to either `document` or `document.body`.

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '#subsearch', function(e) { ... });
```

To illustrate the difference:

```js
$(function() {
  
  // this won't be able to run because #foo isn't in the DOM yet
  $('#foo').on('click', function() {
    console.log('First!');
  });

  // could use '#container' or document.body or any other 
  // already known element here
  $(document).on('click', '#foo', function() {
    console.log('Second!');
  });

  // add #foo after 1 second to simulate content that is injected later
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $('#container').append('<button id="foo">Click me</button>'); 
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$(function(){
  console.log("Document is ready");
});
```

In JQuery for execute any code after document is ready.

In your HTML, please take a care to close your <i> tag.

Comment: Corrected the <i> tag. Was just in the listing wrong. On the page itself it's correct, but I seem to have an issue with the icon..